# Datadog query to filter if a string is contained within a tag

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard, terraform-provider-datadog

I have a parameter, *id*, that populates a monitor for each *id* accordingly.  I am trying to filter the query so that it excludes those where "to_redshift" is contained within the *id*.  Note, "to_redshift" can either be at the prefix, suffix, or somewhere throughout the *id* itself.  How would I go about doing this?

Here is the current query:

```
max(last_1h):airflow.dagrun.duration.success.max{namespace: text} by {id}
```

I have tried

```
max(last_1h):airflow.dagrun.duration.success.max{namespace: text,!id:to_redshift*} by {id}
```

but that is only looking for the prefix and is where i'm currently stuck.  Any help is appreciated!